# excepción no controlada system.io.filenotfoundexception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server

Tengo una aplicación de **consola** realizada en **.net** visual studio 2013,  ya la compile en **Release** y subí el ejecutable  a una carpeta en el servidor, pero al momento de ejecutarla desde el servidor me aparece el siguiente error.

La aplicación lo que hace es conectarce a unas listas de SharePoint ONLINE para insertar unos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual dice: excepción no controlada system.io.filenotfoundexception no se puede cargar el archivo Micorsoft.sharepoint.client, version=15.0.0.0

Comment: Tienes la referencia de la dll añadida en el proyecto? Tienes Microsoft Sharepoint instalado en el servidor? Pon algo más de información para poder darte una mejor respuesta por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu proyecto de Visual Studio debes incluir en referencias las DLLs de

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll (Include)
2. Micrtosoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll(Include)

Así al momento de publicar en Release estarán incluidas en tu proyecto, sino lo haces en el servidor deberías tener instalado [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) que instala estás librerías en el sistema.

Ref: [Respuesta en el foro de Microsoft](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/780a3347-f3bc-4615-91c0-a8cc0fed1441/plugin-error-microsoftsharepointclient-version-15000?forum=crmdevelopment).